# PHP match and replace whole word

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi I am replacing certain names with different value . Here is values I am replacing `"@size-name"` and `"@size"` .But the problem is my code replacing only size first and note name for example

```
@size = "replaceword"
@size-name = "replaceword2"
```

But its replacing

```
@size ="replaceword"
@size-name = "replaceword2-name"
```

How can I replace whole word not part of it here is my code

```
$tempOutQuery = preg_replace("/(\b($key)\b)/i" , $value  , $tempOutQuery);
   $tempOutQuery=  str_replace("@".$key ,$value ,$tempOutQuery);
```

both codes are not working

My Full Code

```
$val= "Hi I want @size dress which is @size-name";

$tempOutQuery = preg_replace("/(\b(size)\b)/i" ,"replaceword", $tempOutQuery);
$tempOutQuery = preg_replace("/(\b(size-name)\b)/i" ,"replaceword2", $tempOutQuery);
```

Comment: i added small code to explain you what i want please check thank you

Comment: I corrected some mistypes, but I need to know what exactly you need to get (it means, what should be final text).

Answer (score 1):

If you could make replace without using regulat expressions, then I would suggest using standart `str_replace()` with arrays:

```
$val= "Hi i want @size dress which is @size-name";

$search  = array('size-name', 'size');
$replace = array('replaceword2', 'replaceword');

$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $val);
```

> **The order of search and replace Strings is important!**
>   You should take care that you replace long search-strings first, and the short strings later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option for you, using `preg_replace_callback`.  It's actually very similar to Gennadiy's method.  The only real difference is that it's using the `preg` aspect of PHP (and it's a lot more work).  But it's another way to skin the proverbial cat.

```
<?php

// SET OUR DEFAULT STRING
$string = 'Hi I want @size suit which is @size-name';

// LOOK FOR EITHER size-name OR size AND IF YOU FIND IT ...
// RUN THE FUNCTION 'replace_sizes'
$string = preg_replace_callback('~@(size-name|size)~', 'replace_sizes', $string);

// PRINT OUT OUR MODIFIED STRING
print $string;




// THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT WILL BE RUN EVERY TIME A MATCH IS FOUND
// EITHER 'size' OR 'size-name' WILL BE STORED IN $m[1]
function replace_sizes($m) {

    // SET UP AN ARRAY THAT HAS OUR POTENTIAL MATCHES AS KEYS
    // AND THE TEXT WE WANT TO REPLACE WITH AS THE VALUE
    $size_text_array = array('size-name' => 'replaceword2', 'size' => 'replaceword');

    // RETURN WHATEVER THE VALUE IS BASED ON THE KEY
    return $size_text_array[$m[1]];

}
```

This will print out:

```
Hi I want replaceword suit which is replaceword2
```

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/njNTbB